# TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

Tags: python, pandas

I have several dataframes (of the same shape) that I want to append creating one larger data-frame.  Tee individual data-frames all have the type:

```
C-Mastersheet.xlsx   <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
D-Mastersheet.xlsx   <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
L-Mastersheet.xlsx   <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

and look like:

C-Mastersheet.xlsx

```
   First Name  Last name        Dept  Location  Status      Concat 
0          Jo      Jones    Accounts   Bristol Current     JonesJo
1         Sid      Smith       Sales      Hull     New    SmithSid
```

D-Mastersheet.xlsx

```
       First Name  Last name        Dept  Location  Status      Concat 
0            Phil      Evans  Production      Hull Current   EvansPhil
1           Sarah      Heath   Marketing   Bristol Current  HeathSarah
2            Jane       Hill    Accounts   Bristol Current    HillJane
3             Amy     Cooper       Sales      Hull Current   CooperAmy
```

L-Mastersheet.xlsx

```
   First Name  Last name        Dept  Location  Status      Concat
0      Marcus      Price  Operations      Hull Current PriceMarcus
1      Andrew       King      Design   Bristol Current  KingAndrew
2        Emma       Lane   Marketing   Bristol Current    LaneEmma
3       Brian       Deen    Accounts   Bristol Current   DeenBrian       
4       Steve      Jacks      Design   Bristol Current  JacksSteve
```

I am trying to return the output:

```
  First Name  Last name        Dept  Location   Status      Concat 
 0         Jo      Jones    Accounts   Bristol Current     JonesJo
 1        Sid      Smith       Sales      Hull New        SmithSid
 2       Phil      Evans  Production      Hull Current   EvansPhil
 3      Sarah      Heath   Marketing   Bristol Current  HeathSarah
 4       Jane       Hill    Accounts   Bristol Current    HillJane
 5        Amy     Cooper       Sales      Hull Current   CooperAmy
 6     Marcus      Price  Operations      Hull Current PriceMarcus
 7     Andrew       King      Design   Bristol Current  KingAndrew
 8       Emma       Lane   Marketing   Bristol Current    LaneEmma
 9      Brian       Deen    Accounts   Bristol Current   DeenBrian       
10      Steve      Jacks      Design   Bristol Current  JacksSteve
```

I am trying to do this using the follwing code whioch loops around a directory:

```
ConsolidatedData = pd.DataFrame

for i in os.listdir(os.chdir(returnsfolder)):
    if i.endswith(".xlsx"):
        )
        rawFilePath = returnsfolder +'\\'+ i

        DeptReturn = openRawDeptReturn(rawFilePath)

        ConsolidatedData = ConsolidatedData.append(DeptReturn,ignore_index=True)
```

I am however getting the following type error:

```
TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

I have not come across this before.

Comment: shouldn't this be `ConsolidatedData = pd.DataFrame()`?

Comment: Yep, that would be it ....

Comment: Probably should delete this question as it's a typo

Comment: @EdChum, Or (let's not brush aside this explanation), a fundamental misunderstanding between class and class instance!

Comment: @jpp Sure, but this _is_ an error as a result of a typo and not likely to be helpful to future visitors. I would keep your answer but also VTC.

Answer (score 35):

This is the problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame           # returns class
df = df.append(DeptReturn)  # TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

The reason behind the error is the *first* argument of a method is the class instance. In this case, the class instance is inferred to be `DeptReturn` and there is no `'other'` argument supplied.

What you need is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()         # returns class instance
df = df.append(DeptReturn)  # returns instance with method applied
```

For the first argument we have the class *instance* `df`, since the method is being applied on that instance. The second argument is `DeptReturn`.

See also: [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)